# Filter app for front camera devices only

Tags: android, manifest, android-camera2, front-camera

I am building an app that requires a front camera to work, I can check in runtime the list of available cameras with `CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)` 
and compare with `CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT`

But is there a way in the camera2 api or using the android manifest to filter the application so that it can only be installed on devices that have a front camera?

This is what I have declared in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add this feature:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="true" />
```

But this ALSO assumes that your app uses a `android.hardware.camera`. And that's usually not a problem and devices with front camera usually have the back camera. But if you do not want that then add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: But can you clarify the difference between using android.hardware.camera2 and android.hardware.camera on the uses-feature? I am using Camera2 API from android.hardware.Camera2 in my app.

Comment: You are using Camera2 Api, thats great. But that does not mean you have to use `android.hardware.camera2` in the manifest uses features. Actual it does not even exist in the list here in the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#hw-features

Answer (score 0):

Add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true"/>` to your manifest.

See [the `<uses-feature>` documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#hw-features) for more about how to restrict your app to devices that have a front-facing camera, etc.